# Wordpress admin_post hook not working => wp-load not found in admin-post.php?

Tags: wordpress, forms, post, action

I'm developing a front-end post submission plugin, and I wanted to leverage the Wordpress approach to submit POST data, ie admin_post_{action} hooks.

So I have created a form that appears in the front-end :

```
<form id="new_post" name="new_post" method="post" action="<?= esc_url(admin_url('admin-post.php')); ?>">
... 
<input type="submit" value="SUBMIT" id="draft" name="draft" />
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="my_action" />
</form>
```

I added the following action to my plugin : 
add_action( 'admin_post_my_action', 'my_form_submission_callback');

However when I press the "submit" button the process redirects me to the site's home page, and xdebug tells me that it doesn't even reach my callback.

I've done some xdebug on the admin-post.php file, and actually the call dies at that step :

```
if ( defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    require_once ABSPATH . 'wp-load.php';
} else {
    require_once dirname( __DIR__ ) . '/wp-load.php';
}
```

Apparently ABSPATH isn't defined and when entering `require_once dirname( __DIR__ ) . '/wp-load.php';` it doesn't find the file and triggers an error.

I'm currently working on a local version of the website, using WAMPP server, PHP version is 7.2.18, WP is the latest (5.4).

Does someone have any idea why this is happening ?

Thanks in advance for your help !

Pascal.

Comment: Hey Pascal, two Qs - maybe you can edit your question to clarify. Are you indeed submitting via AJAX? And also, what is the context of your submission? Is the form rendered inside WP-admin?

Comment: Hi Cameron, thanks for your comment. I've edited my question to clarify that I'm not submitting via AJAX but instead from a form which is rendered in the front end, not on the admin side. Hope that helps !